# WCF UserName clientCredentialType

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, membership-provider

I have a WCF service with following configuration:

```
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="Service1">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MembershipBinding"
                      name="ASPmemberUserName" contract="TestWcfService.IService1" />           
        </service>
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MembershipBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
```

I want to pass the username to the service proxy on client and retrieve it on the server side. I use bellow code to pass the user name to the proxy class:

```
Service1Client sc = new Service1Client();

sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

When I try to retrieve the username on the server, the `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` returns null. Any ideas why it acts like this?

Comment: I noticed that the name of your `service` element is just `Service1` but the name of contract is `TestWcfService.IService1`. Is `Service1` defined in the same namespace? If so you must use the whole name. Your current configuration is probably not used at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by certificate settings. Below link helped solve the issue:

[A simple WCF service with username password authentication: the things they don’t tell you](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/)

Comment: dead link, @Nima M.